# Order a custom post type admin screen by a second custom post type title

Tags: custom-post-types, sql, sort, columns

[image]

I have two custom post types: Products and Brands.  The Product slug is 'eproduct'.  The Brand slug is 'brand-listing'.  On the Product admin page, I have added a custom column that lists the Brand name.  I am trying to make the "Brand" custom column sortable by the brand title (post_title of the Brand custom post type associated with that product).  This is the code I have so far, using the `posts_clauses` filter.

```
add_filter('posts_clauses', 'vendia_sort_brand_column',10,2);
function vendia_sort_brand_column( $clauses, $query ) {
global $wpdb;

if ( ! $query->is_main_query()
    || ! is_admin()
    || ! $query->get('post_type') == 'eproduct'
){
    return $clauses;
}

$clauses['orderby'] = " {$wpdb->posts}.post_title ";

return $clauses;
}
```

As shown above, I have tried to modify the `orderby` parameter of the SQL query, using the `post_clauses` filter.

`$clauses['orderby'] = " {$wpdb->posts}.post_title";`

My stumbling block is that both the "Brand" and "Product" custom post types are in the wp_posts table. So `{$wpdb->posts}.post_title` returns the Product title,  not the Brand title that I am trying to order by.  Thus, my Product admin page is simply sorted by Product title, not Brand title.

What I want to do is something like this

`$clauses['orderby'] = " {$wpdb->posts}.post_title WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'brand-listing'";`

The key change is that I have added `WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'brand-listing'` to the `ORDERBY` clause.  However, apparently that is not valid SQL.  My query returns 0 posts, and thus my Products admin screen lists no posts. I guess a `WHERE` clause is not allowed inside an `ORDERBY` clause?  Or is it?

I am a novice to SQL, so I am wondering, what would be the valid SQL `ORDERBY` clause to accomplish what I am trying to do?

I thank anyone who replies, for any help.  I have been working on this for light years.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your mixing slug and post-type. Slug is used to identify a page/post when some entering it into the browser (very related to a permalink). A post type is used to identify what kind of post that is stored in the wordpress database.

`post_clauses` is used if you want to change several things in a query at once. I would recommend using `pre_get_posts` instead (if you don't want to do more complex queries than ordering)

Based on what you've wrote:

```
$clauses['orderby'] = " {$wpdb->posts}.post_title WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'brand-listing'";
```

it seems like you only want orderby posts that custom post type **brand** (not brand-listing that seems to be the slug?)

```
/* Sort posts in wplist admin */
function custom_post_order($query){
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || ! is_admin() {return;}

    $post_type = $query->get('post_type');

    if ($post_type == 'brand') {            
        $query->set( 'orderby', array('title' => 'ASC') );
    }

}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_order');
```

This won't work...

```
$clauses['orderby'] = " {$wpdb->posts}.post_title WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'brand-listing'";
```

...because Wordpress uses the **orderby-argument** here to include **orderby** **only**.

(I guess WP would create a query something like this:

```
order by wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'brand-listing'
where wp_posts_type = 'post' //default created by wordpress
```

and therefore sql is incorrect (two where clauses)
)

If you still want to use `post_clauses` you should be able to use this:

```
$clauses['orderby'] = "{$wpdb->posts}.post_title";
$clauses['where'] = "{$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'brand'";
```

Comment: This does not work because, on the Product admin screen, $post_type is 'eproduct', not 'brand-listing' like you have in your if statement (you actually have 'brand').
The full SQL query right now is:
`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'eproduct' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC LIMIT 0, 20`

Comment: Replace brand with eproduct then? (In my answer)

Comment: I think now you're starting to see the problem I was trying to describe.  It's tricky to explain.  The post_type of the **page** is already "eproduct".   Setting `if ($post_type == 'eproduct')` is redundant.  It's the Product admin screen, so the post_type is already 'eproduct'.  What  I'm trying to do is sort by the `title` of a particular **column** on that page that has a post_type of "brand-listing".

Comment: Im not sure I do understand. Are you able to upload an image of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yea.  I  uploaded an image.  You can see at the top it says "Product Listings".  That's the Product custom post type admin screen.  You can see there is a column named "Brand".  It's a custom column I added and registered to be sortable.  It displays the name (post title) of the Brand associated with the Product.  
The Brand column is already displaying what it needs to display, and is already registered as sortable.  Now I just need to define the right sort function.
The sort function should sort the Products admin page by the "Brand" column. 
Does that help any?

Comment: What happens If you try my code?

Comment: See my very first comment.  I pasted the SQL query verbatim.  The result is that WordPress orders the list of products on the product admin screen by wp_posts.post_title.  The **Product** post title, not the **Brand** post title.

Comment: Hm There are no such thing as a brandtitle. Post_title is used for all posts. You filter it out by the post_type column. And your sql looks correct.

Comment: Yea I know...that's my problem.  post_title is the only field.  Both the `brand-listing` (Brand) custom post type and the `eproduct` (Product) custom post type are in the same table (wp_posts) and share the same field (post_title).  So how do I order by ONLY the Brand custom post type titles, not the Product custom post type titles, on a page where $post_type is `eproduct` (lists as the Product post types).  There is one column, "Brand", that lists the post_title of custom post type `brand-listing`.  How do I order by post_title of just that column?

Comment: Does this help? :-) http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/06/27/custom-columns-for-custom-post-types

Comment: No it did not, sorry.

Comment: I'm really confused and I'm sorry but I don't understand the issue at all. Post-type cannot be different on the admin-page vs the frontend page. I mean a product cannot be "productX" on the adminpage and "productY" on the frontend page.